# How to make a table in ReactJS sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am building a simple app in ReactJS that works with a JSON array by calling a certain API. I am then populating the results of the array in a table. I now wanted to make the columns of the table sortable. Can someone help me with that. Here is my code.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://hostname:xxxx/yyyy/zzzz")
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(items => this.setState({ data: items }));
  }

  render() {
    var newdata = this.state.data;

    return (
      <table className="m-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>AccountName</th>
            <th>ContractValue</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {newdata.map(function(account, index) {
            return (
              <tr key={index} data-item={account}>
                <td data-title="Account">{account.accountname}</td>
                <td data-title="Value">{account.negotiatedcontractvalue}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: i will suggest you to use `react-bootstrap-table` it provides all the features including the sorting by default, check this: http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/start.html column sorting example: http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#sort

Comment: I am using custom features also, like (clicking on the table row to pull rowID and do something). So I can't use `react-bootstrap-table`. I am looking for the code to add.

Comment: Since you are rendering your table from data, you simply sort the data and re-render. Does that make sense?

Comment: I wanted to sort from the table header. I want to make use of that feature in other tables also

Answer (score 37):

Here's a quick example of how to do it, based on my comment:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
    this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://hostname:xxxx/yyyy/zzzz")
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(items => this.setState({ data: items }));
  }

  onSort(event, sortKey){
    /*
    assuming your data is something like
    [
      {accountname:'foo', negotiatedcontractvalue:'bar'},
      {accountname:'monkey', negotiatedcontractvalue:'spank'},
      {accountname:'chicken', negotiatedcontractvalue:'dance'},
    ]
    */
    const data = this.state.data;
    data.sort((a,b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]))
    this.setState({data})
  }

  render() {
    var newdata = this.state.data;

    return (
      <table className="m-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'accountname')}>AccountName</th>
            <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'negotiatedcontractvalue')}>ContractValue</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {newdata.map(function(account, index) {
            return (
              <tr key={index} data-item={account}>
                <td data-title="Account">{account.accountname}</td>
                <td data-title="Value">{account.negotiatedcontractvalue}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I ideally want is to have both ascending and descending sorting. Once I click on the header when it is sorted ascending, it should sort descending and vice-versa.

Comment: @MidhunMathewSunny you should be able to figure out how to do that from the example...give it a shot and if you can't get it working post another question

Comment: I have added another question as you asked. I don't have much time to explore. It would be great if you could post the answer quickly.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402937/how-to-make-columns-in-table-sortable-in-both-ways-using-reactjs]

Comment: @PedroJR Right, because it is using local state in a class component. You could get it to work in a functional component by using state hooks, or extracting it into the store of your choice.