# In react js I need to get a design for up and down arrow toggle for sorting columns of a table

Tags: reactjs, html-table, semantic-ui

In react js I need to get a design for up and down toggle arrow for sorting columns of a table

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll find a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44375705/6153188).

Comment: May I urge you to have a look here before: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: question is slightly unclear, and you should explain what you have tried or looked in to

Answer (score 0):

material-ui provides the [tools](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tables/) for that.